# AEM redirecting from unsecured URL to AEM secured website

Tags: aem, dispatcher

Currently  clients have 20+ URLs which when user types will be redirected to one common website.

```
Ex: www.example.x will redirect to http://www.example.com/x
```

In AEM, will there be any problem if all these 20+ websites are unsecured (HTTP) and common website is secured(HTTPS).

```
Ex: www.example.x will redirect to https://www.example.com/x
```

Also, is it possible to handle this in the dispatcher.  Any rules which allows this.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you are redirecting from http to https. It should.

You can write a rewrite condition which will rewrite the protocol

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://your.url [L,R]
```